# how does SurfaceView class functions work when their function defination is empty?

Tags: android, android-canvas

i am new to android .
i was working with android canvas and i wonder how does SurfaceView class functions work when their function defination is empty in the android source code .Here is the android surface view class source code

```
package android.view;

import com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.util.AttributeSet;


public class SurfaceView extends MockView {

public SurfaceView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public SurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs , 0);
}

public SurfaceView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public SurfaceHolder getHolder() {
    return mSurfaceHolder;
}

private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder = new SurfaceHolder() {

    @Override
    public boolean isCreating() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void addCallback(Callback callback) {
    }

    @Override
    public void removeCallback(Callback callback) {
    }

    @Override
    public void setFixedSize(int width, int height) {
    }

    @Override
    public void setSizeFromLayout() {
    }

    @Override
    public void setFormat(int format) {
    }

    @Override
    public void setType(int type) {
    }

    @Override
    public void setKeepScreenOn(boolean screenOn) {
    }

    @Override
    public Canvas lockCanvas() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Canvas lockCanvas(Rect dirty) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void unlockCanvasAndPost(Canvas canvas) {
    }

    @Override
    public Surface getSurface() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public Rect getSurfaceFrame() {
        return null;
    }
};
}
```

so how does this work when we write

```
canvas c = holder.lockCanvas(null);
```

or

```
holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
```

when we have nothing in source code to process.. i mean where is the code to get the work done. if help me find it..

Answer (score 0):

The full SurfaceView source code is in the AOSP code on Github:
https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/view/SurfaceView.java

Comment: thanks but why was it not showing in the android source code given in the sdk

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're looking at the source for the stub library.

For the SDK, a library is generated that has entries for all public classes, fields, and methods, but no implementation.  You build your app against that, rather than the actual library, so that your build fails if you try to use classes, fields, or methods that aren't part of the official Android API.

If you look in the actual [source for SurfaceView](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/kitkat-release/core/java/android/view/SurfaceView.java) you will see methods like `setWindowType()` (line 415) that have `@hide` in the javadoc.  Even though the method is "public" in the Java-language sense, it's not part of the published API, and is therefore excluded from the stub library.